# Cut Ubuntu version from lsb-releases to variable in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to cut out the Ubuntu version from etc/lsb-releases to a variable.
I have managed to cut out this line DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04 but would like to only have 16.04 instead the entire line

```
# Get ubuntu version
file="/home/test/Desktop/lsb-release"
ubuntu_v=$(cat "$file" | grep DISTRIB_RELEASE) 
echo $ubuntu_v
```

I used the  code above to cut the line DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04, how do I save only the 16.04 part to a variable?

Comment: Why don't you source the file `/etc/os-release` instead? See this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450298/how-to-get-ubuntu-distributions-full-code-name/450520#450520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` directly on the `lsb-release` file. And you could split the output with [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28Unix%29). Something like,

```
$ grep DISTRIB_RELEASE /etc/lsb-release | cut -f2 -d'='
```

And, to match your example

```
file=/etc/lsb-release
ubuntu_v=$(grep DISTRIB_RELEASE "$file" | cut -f2 -d'=')
```

**Alternatively**, use [`source`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_%28command%29) and access `DISTRIB_RELEASE` with the environment directly like

```
source /etc/lsb-release
echo $DISTRIB_RELEASE
```

you then get all of the release variables, and could also

```
echo $DISTRIB_ID
echo $DISTRIB_CODENAME
echo $DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you awk to get that info:

```
var=`awk -F '=' '{if($1 == "DISTRIB_RELEASE") print $2}' /etc/lsb-release`
```